# Why do i get this ^@ when i attempt to access the first element of a CvMat data struct member

Tags: c++, opencv

when i run this code

```
      double a[]={1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0};
      CvMat M=cvMat(8,8,CV_8UC1, a);
      cout<<"M.data.ptr="<< M.data.ptr[0]<<endl;
```

to access a 1.0, the first element of the matrix, i get the output `M.data.ptr=^@`
oddly enough i tried copying the cout output into this ? and the `^@` wouldn't copy..i got only `M.data.ptr` when i pasted...I tied other variations like `M.data.ptr[0]` and `M.data.ptr` but just got normal error and null output  for those 2 respectively.
how would i go about accessing the 1.0 by dereferencing the data struct member and not using a function i/e cvGet2D...just in case its emacs thats doing this i thought id report im using Emacs on Ubuntu Saucy...

Comment: C does not use `cout<<"M.data.ptr=" ...`.  Maybe you want C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to initialize a matrix with elements of type `double`, but creating matrix of type `CV_8UC1`. Also, directly accessing the pointer will return the raw pointer (of type `unsigned char`) to the underlying data. You have to interpret that pointer as `double*` to get the actual values.
What you are trying to do may actually look something like this:

```
double a[]={1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0};
CvMat M = cvMat(8,8,CV_64FC1, a);

double* data_ptr_64f = (double*)(M.data.ptr);

cout<<"M.data.ptr="<< data_ptr_64f[0]<<endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't read the correct number of bytes. The `data` field has size 8 bits (uchar). You should either cast the pointer:

```
cout << *((double *)M.data.ptr) << endl;
```

or use the getters that OpenCV kindly provides you:

```
cout << M.at<double>(0, 0) << endl;

/* yet another possibility */
cout << *M.ptr<double>(0) << endl;
```